# Accessing index values from an ArrayList and storing them in a seperate new ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing, iteration

[image: diagram to help explain question]

I currently have an `ArrayList` called months.

`ArrayList<MonthData> months;`

`MonthData` is a class that is basically a model for data.

```
public class MonthData {

  int y;
  int m;
  float h;
  ...


  public MonthData(String data) throws Exception {
    ...
    this.parseData(data);
  }


  void parseData(String csvData) {
    String[] parseResult = csvData.trim().split("\\s+");

    this.setYear(parseResult[0]);
    this.setMonth(parseResult[1]);
    ...


  public String toString() {
    return "y =" + year + ", m =" + month + ",...

  }


  public int getY() {
    return y;
  }

  // followed by lots of getters for: m, h, c, f, r, s, ...
```

Now for the second public class...

```
public class Totals {
  private ArrayList<MonthData> months;


  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, Exception {
    Totals t = new Totals("..blah/../..blah/../Numbers.data");

  }

  public void readDataFile(String filename) throws IOException, Exception {
    FileReader file = new FileReader(filename);
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);
    String line;

    buffer.readLine(); //skipping headers
    ...

    while (!(line = buffer.readLine()).isEmpty()) {
      this.months.add(new MonthData(line.trim()));
    }

    buffer.close();
    System.out.println(this.months);
  }
```

This class reads a file containing lots of data, here is a snippet of the data:

```
     y    m      h       c       f      r       s //here for your reference

   1930   1    8.1     2.4       6   120.5    54.2
   1930   2    4.4     0.6      12    22.2    29.1
   1930   3    8.1     2.1       9    76.2    88.2
    ...
```

When I `System.out.println(this.months);`

I get this:

`y=1930, m=1, h=8.1, c=2.4, f=6, r=120.5, s=54.2, y =1930, m=2, h=4.4, c=0.6, f=12, r=22.2, s=29.1, ...` etc.

As you can see it corresponds with the data file so I know the data is being read to the `ArrayList months` properly.

******** QUESTION ***********
Now what I want to do is look at this ArrayList and **get every r value and store them in a different ArrayList, lets say `ArrayList rValues` (so that i have an ArrayList full of r values only).**

I know I need to iterate over this ArrayList somehow to the r value indexes, get the values and then store them in another ArrayList just dont know how!! :(

Any help here at all will be greatly appreciated. Happy to answer any questions, although i have possibly explained whats going on as best as i can. Thanks in advance guys :)

Comment: offset downvote because i love such presentation of questions.

Comment: What is the specific problem here?  Presumably you know how to call `getR` on a given instance, and know how to iterate over all instances, and how to add things to an ArrayList.  So in which case, where are you stuck in putting this all together?

Comment: no, i dont know how to do it @OliverCharlesworth. This is the problem, i know what needs doing just not the how to correctly do so part

Comment: **Which part** are you stuck with?

Comment: I cant do the for loop that iterates over the arraylist.

Comment: thanks @HuStmpHrrr worth taking the time to fully explain :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you iterate over list like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<months.size(); i++)
```

and then you can get your MonthData object with this command

```
months.get(i)
```

and if you want just a r value then create getter for r (`getR()`) and call it and save in new array list:

Something like this:

```
ArrayList<Float> rValue = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i<months.size(); i++)
{
    rValue.add(months.get(i).getR());
}
```

(thanks to @Mick Mnemonic)
You can also use [foreach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) loop

```
ArrayList<Float> rValue = new ArrayList<>();
for (MonthData m: months) 
{ 
    rValue.add(m.getR()); 
}
```

Comment: THANKYOU!! I just didnt know how to put it all together. :)
`rValue.add(months.get(i).getR());`
was what i needed!
answer accepted!

Comment: Because the index variable (`i`) is not needed here, it's simpler to use the [for-each loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html): `for (MonthData m: months) { rValue.add(m.getR()); }`.

Comment: @MickMnemonic added to answer. Thanks

Comment: And easier still with `months.forEach(m -> { rValue.add(m.getR(); } );` - with Java 8 as pointed out.

Comment: ...if OP is using Java 8, yes.

Comment: sadly im not using java 8, but thanks @MickMnemonic for the further improvement :)